# Response emails being save as "file" file-type

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am curious to know as to why every response email and forwarded emails are not being saved with the .msg file extension. Instead, they are being saved as .file extension. Any reason as to why this is happening and how to fix the problem? This is the code that I am working on right now.

```
Public Sub SaveMsgs(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

 'Declare Variables
 Dim sPath As String
 Dim dtDate As Date
 Dim sName As String
 Dim sSubject As String
 Dim enviro As String
 Dim sSender As String
 Dim strFolder As String
 Dim strNewFolder As String
 Dim save_to_folder As String

 'enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))

 ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"

 sSender = Item.Sender

 dtDate = Item.ReceivedTime
 'sName = sSender & " - " & sSubject & ".msg"

 'Set Folder path
 strNewFolder = Format(dtDate, "mm-dd-yyyy")
 strFolder = "C:\IT Documents\" & strNewFolder & "\"

 'Determine if there is subject
 If Len(Item.Subject) > 0 Then
   sSubject = Item.Subject
 Else
   sSubject = "No Subject "
 End If

 'Determine if folder is in the directory
 If Len(Dir(strFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir (strFolder)
 End If

 sName = sSender & " - " & sSubject
 save_to_folder = strFolder

 Item.SaveAs save_to_folder & sName & ".msg"
End Sub
```

Comment: can you still open the emails that are being save as dot files?

Comment: I can not open those emails. I have also tried renaming the files to .msg, but when i do that, it is saying that I do not have the permissions to view the file, even when I have full control permissions set on the folder for myself.

Comment: okay try again and let me know, make sure you copy all the code exactly and **do not edit** , all the email should be saved as `".msg"`

Comment: I just tried this, copied everything the way that it is, have the right references, but still every response and forwarded message still get saved as a .file rather than .msg

Answer (score 0):

make sure you reference

```
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Microsoft outlook Object Library
Microsoft Word Object Library
```

[image]

the following code has been tested on <kbd>**Outlook 2010**</kbd>

```
Option Explicit
'// Save the message as a native .msg
Public Sub SaveMsg(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim SavePath As String
    Dim TimeDate As Date
    Dim SaveName As String
    Dim Enviro As String
    Dim NewFolder As String
    Dim EmailSubject As String

    '// enviro gets the user account part of the path
    '// so you can use the same code on different computers
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ReplaceCharsForFileName SaveName, "_"

    '// Use My Documents for older Windows.
    NewFolder = "C:\IT Documents\" & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "\"

    '// Test if directory or file exists
    If FileOrDirExists(NewFolder) Then
        MsgBox NewFolder & " exists!"
    Else
        MkDir NewFolder
    End If

    EmailSubject = FileName(Item.Subject)

    '// Determine if there is subject
    If Item.Subject <> vbNullString Then
        EmailSubject = Item.Subject
    Else
        EmailSubject = "No Subject"
    End If


    '// Get Email subject & set name to be saved as
    TimeDate = Item.ReceivedTime
    SaveName = Format(TimeDate, "YYYYMMDD", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & Format(TimeDate, "-HHNNSS", _
    vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & EmailSubject & SaveName & ".msg"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")



    '// Save .msg File
    SavePath = "C:\IT Documents\" & NewFolder & "\"
    Debug.Print NewFolder & SaveName
    Item.SaveAs NewFolder & SaveName, olMsg

End Sub

'// This function removes invalid and other characters from file names
Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(SaveName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "/", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "\", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, ":", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "?", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, Chr(34), sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "<", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, ">", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "|", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "&", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "%", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "*", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, " ", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "{", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "[", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "]", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "}", sChr)
  SaveName = Replace(SaveName, "!", sChr)

End Sub

'// Good practice suggests that it is wise to check before taking certain actions
'// This function checks if File or Dir Exists
Function FileOrDirExists(PathName As String) As Boolean
    Dim iTemp As Integer

     '// Ignore errors to allow for error evaluation
    On Error Resume Next
    iTemp = GetAttr(PathName)

     '// Check if error exists and set response appropriately
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Is = 0
        FileOrDirExists = True
    Case Else
        FileOrDirExists = False
    End Select

     '// Resume error checking
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function FileName(strText As String) As String
    Dim strStripChars As String
    Dim intLen As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    strStripChars = "/\[]:=," & Chr(34)
        intLen = Len(strStripChars)
    strText = Trim(strText)
        For i = 1 To intLen
    strText = Replace(strText, Mid(strStripChars, i, 1), "")

    Next
    FileName = strText
End Function
```

good luck.

Comment: That would never work - * is no a valid character in a file name

Comment: @Omar Ok, I will give this a shot and see how it works out for me. Quick question though, howcome it would matter if I created a module rather than adding the code to the **ThisOutlookSession module**? Essentially, could I just add this code to the module which I already have created or no?

Comment: You do not have to use ThisOutlookSession is just an example if you want to.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is still there. The email is being saved as a .file, rather than .msg